# Appending Array in a loop with certain format

Tags: php, loops

I am struggling to append data retreived from an SQL query in PHP. Basically I have this so far -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE productId = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
           extract($row);
       $response["Sales"][]["Products"]["SaleProduct"] = array('ProductName'=>$ProductName);
     }
}
```

This will work for the most part. It will append to each array, however where I am stumbling is if the SQL returns more than 1 row...

Baically I am tryign to return an array in a web service, it will return "Sales" made. Each Sale could have many products in it. With the code I have so far it only caters for one product per sale. If 2 products are sold then it will essentially create 2 sales with 1 product each.

Can anyone guide me in the correct way to be able to get what I need?

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected array format ? Also extract is not necessary here. `array('ProductName'=>$ProductName)` can be written as `array('ProductName'=>$row['ProductName'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, this sounds like what you are after:

```
$response["Sales"]["Products"][] = array('ProductName'=>$ProductName);
```

The general problem is that you are not using the `[]` syntax carefully enough. It's a good idea to only use that *at the end* of the expression.

Comment: I had tried this, I was unable to serialise the result though